# jQuery use loop instead of hardcoding

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops

I have the following statement(s) in my wp site to activate my galleries on my tabs:

```
jQuery("ul.tabs a").click(function(){ 
  jQuery('#DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery1').DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery();
});
```

I do this for each `#DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery` I use (so `#DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery1, #DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery2, etc`). I would like to do this in a loop instead of hardcoding it. How can I do the click for `#DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery`*?

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: just use the same class in all? o.O

Comment: @Vandesh post that as an answer. It's much more elegant (and semantic) than using an 'attribute starts with' selector on the `id`

Comment: You can keep the ID's if you wish, but add a class as Vandesh suggests, and you'll have a much simpler time.

Answer (score 2):

Using an attribute starts with an id syntax has performance impact.
Rather, apply the same class to all - say `myCommonClass` and then do something like

```
jQuery("ul.tabs a").click(function(){ 
$(".myCommonClass").DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery();
});
```

**Why performance is bad in ID starts with selector?** -

1. It performs a check against an attribute - 'id'.
2. String comparison with each element in the DOM if you use `$("id^...")`

Comment: The HTML code I reference has been generated by wordpress. The commonclass sadly has no id. If I use $("id^...) my browser locks up... so I do see the performance issue.

Comment: No matter what I try it either does not work or it will completely lock up my browser. I have no id of the common class.

Comment: can you post the HTML structure of the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
 jQuery("[id^='DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery']").DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery();
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: So in total it would be: jQuery("ul.tabs a").click(function(){ jQuery("['id^=DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery']").DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery();}); ?

Comment: Better to use class naming, rather than starts-with on sequential ids, unless that cannot be avoided (e.g. if the generated display data is not under your control). start-with is also a little slower (and less obvious).

Comment: I am sorry I am very new to jQuery.
`code` jQuery("ul.tabs a").click(function(){ jQuery("['id^=DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery']").DOPNextGENThumbnailGallery();}); `code`

did not work for me.

Comment: @user2890644 : Try to avoid comments like above and learn to get better. Welcome to StackOverflow